# Code Design when Dealing with Large Numbers of Instance Attributes in Python

Tags: python, instance-variables, readability, code-readability

So I'm writing a program in Python, and it's getting rather long. As I've expanded it, I've started to notice that some of my classes are getting many attributes, and I'm passing them into __init__ in a way that just feels suboptimal. As an example, here's what I'm talking about:

```
class Enemy(Ship):

def __init__(self,m=20000,size=32,F=[0,0],X=[0,0],v=[0,0],a=[0,0],p=[0,0],
             tau=0,theta=0,omega=0,alpha=0,I=850000,rel_X_cm=[16,16],sprites=[pygame.image.load("core_off.png"),pygame.image.load("core_on.png")],
             health=0,module_type="Thruster",module_coordinates=[0,0],core_module=None,
             module_orientation=0,F_max=[4000000,0],tau_max=0,
             attached_modules=[],surrounding_points = [[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]]):

    super(Enemy,self).__init__(m,size,F,X,v,a,p,tau,theta,
                                  omega,alpha,I,rel_X_cm,sprites,
                                  health,module_type,module_coordinates,
                                  core_module,module_orientation,F_max,tau_max,
                                  attached_modules,surrounding_points)
```

This is obviously pretty messy, and I'd prefer to simplify my code. So my question is, is there a better way to handle all of these variables than the way I'm doing it?

Comment: This isn't a Python-specific problem, see e.g. https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/long-parameter-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what unpacking arguments are for. And in this case since you are passing [*keyword arguments*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) you can use `**kwargs`:

```
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    # do stuff with kwargs[X] which X is the name of your argument
```

And for your [*positional arguments*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) you can use one star prefix `*args` which lets you pass  arbitrary argument list to function:

```
def __init__(self,*args):
      # then you can loop over the args in order to achieve to arguments
```

Comment: Is there a way to define default values for unknown numbers of variables? Thanks!

Comment: @AustinGarrett If they're unknown how do you know what the defaults should be?

Comment: @AustinGarrett Can you describe your question with an example? you can update your question with new info.

Comment: I came up with a solution; I just define a class dict called "default_params" and then within \_\_init\_\_ I use
`for var in default_params:
    self.var = kwargs.pop('var',default_params[var])`